# What is the total SATA bandwidth of the Intel Z68 chipset?

Tags: ssd, sata, disk-controller

Take a look at this page for the Intel Z68 chipset: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/mainstream-chipsets/z68-express-chipset.html

In the diagram, the line connecting the chipset to the SATA ports says "Up to 6 Gb/s". Notice it doesn't say *each*, like for some of the others.

My actual question is: Is this telling me the sum of all SATA ports on the Z68 chipset all have to share 6 Gb/s bandwidth?

The reason I'm asking is my motherboard has a Marvell 9128 controller with 2 SATA 6 Gbp/s ports. But I'm being duped: the Marvell controller uses a PCIe 1X lane, which only supports up to 5 Gb/s. Both 6 Gbp/s ports have to share a 5Gb/s lane. I want to be able to use SSDs that I buy to the fullest and not be bottlenecked by the controllers on my motherboard.

> http://www.marvell.com//storage/system-solutions/assets/Marvell-88SE91XX-Host-Controllers.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you need to ensure that every SSD you have will have its full bus speed per SATA port, you may want to consider PCIe -> SATA card.

I think (I have only read Intel Motherboard Technical Description available [here](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/20248/eng/DZ68BC_TechProdSpec08.pdf) - check diagram page 16) that the Z68 chipset sets the standard "Up to 6Gb/s" and each manufacturer can do whatever they want to achieve that.

As shown on the Intel Motherboard (for that particular DZ68BC model), they are also using Marvell Chipset (on PCIe x1) to handle 2 x 6Gb/s SATA connector, and 2 x 6GB/s SATA connector goes directly to the PCH (not via the PCIe x1 channel).

So you may need to go to each Motherboard Manufacturer, check out their technical document to find out exactly how they are handling their SATA connectors, whether it uses Marvell controller with PCIe 1x lane, or directly into the PCH.

Mind you, motherboard bottleneck is not the only possible issue. The  SSD read and write itself could be the bottleneck. On this [link from Tom's Hardware SSD Benchmark](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/ssd-charts-2013/benchmarks,129.html) you will find multiple different program testing read and write speed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Understood. The motherboard I'm working with is the ASUS P8Z68 Deluxe (Gen 1).

Comment: They did specifically say on their [spec](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8Z68_DELUXE/#specifications) that some SATA controllers are handled by the Z68 Chipset PCH, and some are handled by the Marvell Chipset.. and they are color coded accordingly, so that should make your decision easier (and give the answer to your question).